# What Backup Library/Code Do You Use For Your Dataset (Files On Disk)?

Tags: backup, desktop, clarion

I'm implementing Backup functionality into my new (small) app, [Oldaer](http://oldaer.com). I've got standalone desktop files (rather than sitting in a SQL db).

Looking around, I decided on using a Clarion 3rd-Party Template that will package them into one file and then compress (huffman's) that one file. Restoring is just the reverse. Uncompress, unpack.

However, I'm not convinced this is ideal.

**What Backup functionality do you implement for your dataset?**

Of course, there's a lot more in "Backup/Restore" functionality. Location, Tracking/Archiving, Out-of-the-box Information (like better ways of letting the User know what was in the archive file). But that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Replication, clustering, RAID 5

Comment: Thanks tslib. Was kinda hoping for some static files, but I guess most folk work in SQL anyway.

Comment: Ahh.  You still have RAID.  My group backs up our physical data/files on an identical server off-site in a failover config.

Answer (score 0):

Just been playing with uploading datasets to Amazon S3 using the NetTalk 3rd party libraries in Clarion.  Seems to work a treat.  I am working on keeping multiple 'versions' of the dataasets using the MetaTags functionality.

Happy to dig out my code and discuss further if you need.

Comment: Devan,

Hey hey! Good to see another Clarionite on here :)

Will take a squiz at Amazon S3. Sounds like a good online option.